# File copying issue on GlusterFS mounted share

Tags: perl, glusterfs

I am having issue in copying a file to a folder which is basically a GlusterFS mounted share.

My Perl script reads a file, does some parsing, and creates a new file. After that I copy the newly-created file with a different name to a different location.

I get this error

```
bin/cp: skipping file `/gfs_share/abc/xyz/aktar.txt', as it was replaced while being copied
```

My perl code :

```
    foreach my $Id (@Studies){
            my $Trigger_Start_1 = my $Trigger_End_1 = 0;
            open(FILE,"$File_path") or die "In gen : Couldn't open file $File_path $! \n";
            while(<FILE>){
                    chomp($_);
                    if($_ =~ /#INPUT_TYPE\s*(.*)/){
                            next;
                    }if($_ =~ /^ID\s+$Id/){
                            $Trigger_Start_1 = 1;
                            system ("echo 'Startstudy '>> $Input_FilePath/aktar.txt");
                            system ("echo '$_' >> $Input_FilePath/aktar.txt");
                            next;
                    }if(($Trigger_Start_1 == 2) && ($_ =~ /Endstudy/)){
                            $Trigger_End_1 = 0;
                            $Trigger_Start_1 = 0;
                            system ("echo '$_' >> $Input_FilePath/aktar.txt");
                    }
                    if($Trigger_Start_1 == 1){
                            if($_ =~/Disease\d*_run\d*/){
                                    system ("echo '$_' >> $Input_FilePath/aktar.txt");
                                    next;
                            }else{
                                    system ("echo '$_' >> $Input_FilePath/aktar.txt");
                            }
                            $Trigger_Start_1 = 2;
                            next;
                    }
                    if(($Trigger_Start_1 == 2) && ($Trigger_End_1 == 0)){
                            system("echo '$_ ' >> $Input_FilePath/aktar.txt");
                    }
            }
    }
    system ("echo 'Endvalidation '>> $Input_FilePath/aktar.txt");

    close(FILE) or die "In gen : Unable to Close File $! \n";

    `sed "s/#INPUT_TYPE $Input_Type//" input.txt > input1.txt`;
    `sed "s/#DELTA_SET YES 5//" input1.txt > input.txt`;
    `cat input.txt >> $Input_FilePath/aktar.txt`;
    system ("echo 'INPUT : $Input_FilePath'>> $Input_FilePath/aktar.txt");
    system("rm -rf $File_path") if(-e $File_path);
 `/bin/cp $Source_Path/aktar.txt $To_Path`;
```

Comment: It looks like you're shelling out to use `cp` to copy the file; is that right? I suspect that you are doing that before you close the Perl output file handle, but unless you are deliberately starting an asynchronous (background) process to run `cp` I can't see how that would happen. The answer is in your code. Please show your Perl program

Comment: @Borodin: please find the chunk of my perl script which does the copying.

Answer (score 0):

I recoded the code to be pure Perl (rather than shelling out).  Makes it easier to read.  I hope your not using a pre 5.8 Perl from a prior decade or this code would be too "modern".

What I notice is that you expect "$Input_FilePath" to be the same as "$Source_Path".  Is that the case?  Also you parse $Source_Path and input.txt.  Seems unconnected, are they two different files?

```
use File::Path;
use File::Copy;
use FileHandle;

my $aktarfile = "$Input_FilePath/aktar.txt";
my ($inh, $aktarh, $inputh);
open $aktarh, '>>', $aktarfile or die "Unable to open [$aktarfile] for writing\n";
$aktarh->autoflush();
    foreach my $id (@Studies){
        my $Trigger_Start_1 = my $Trigger_End_1 = 0;
        open $inh, '<', $File_path or die "In gen : Couldn't open file $File_path $! \n";
        LINE:
        while(<$inh>){
                chomp($_);
                if($_ =~ /#INPUT_TYPE\s*(.*)/){
                        next LINE;
                }if($_ =~ /^ID\s+$id/){
                        $Trigger_Start_1 = 1;
                        print {$aktarh} "Startstudy\n$_";
                        next LINE;
                }if(($Trigger_Start_1 == 2) && ($_ =~ /Endstudy/)){
                        $Trigger_End_1 = 0;
                        $Trigger_Start_1 = 0;
                        print {$aktarh} $_;
                }
                if($Trigger_Start_1 == 1){
                        print {$aktarh} $_;
                        if($_ !~/Disease\d*_run\d*/){
                            $Trigger_Start_1 = 2;
                        }
                        next LINE;
                }
                if(($Trigger_Start_1 == 2) && ($Trigger_End_1 == 0)){
                  print {$aktarh} $_;
                }
        }
        close $inh or die "In gen : Unable to Close File $! \n";
}
print {$aktarh} "Endvalidation\n";
my $inputfile = 'input.txt';
open $inputh, '<', $inputfile or die "Failed to open [$inputfile] for reading";
while(<$inputh>){
  s/#INPUT_TYPE $Input_Type//;
  s/#DELTA_SET YES 5//;
  print {$aktarh} $_;
}
print {$aktarh} "INPUT : $Input_FilePath\n";
close $aktarh or die "Failed closing [$aktarfile]";
File::Path::remove_tree($File_path) if(-e $File_path);
File::Copy::copy "$Source_Path/aktar.txt",  $To_Path;
```

Comment: Yes, $Input_FilePath and $Source_Path are the same. $Source_Path and input.txt are different files, input.txt is created as an intermediate file.